# Traduction small code Assembly -> C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Update with the code, sorry about that :

Assembly :

```
01:  cmp    edi, 5
02:  ja         short loc_10001141
03:  jmp    ds:off_100011A4[edi*4]
04: loc_10001125:
05:  mov    esi, 40h
06:  jmp    short loc_10001145
07: loc_1000112C:
08:  mov    esi, 20h
09:  jmp    short loc_10001145
10: loc_10001133:
11:  mov    esi, 38h
12:  jmp    short loc_10001145
13: loc_1000113A:
14:  mov    esi, 30h
15:  jmp    short loc_10001145
16: loc_10001141:
17:  mov    esi, [esp+0Ch]
18: …
19: off_100011A4 dd offset loc_10001125
20:     dd offset loc_10001125
21:     dd offset loc_1000113A
22:     dd offset loc_1000112C
23:     dd offset loc_10001133
24:     dd offset loc_1000113A
```

Pseudo C :

```
switch(edi) {
case 0:
case 1:
// goto loc_10001125;
    esi = 0x40;
    break;
case 2:
case 5:
// goto loc_1000113A;
    esi = 0x30;
    break;
case 3:
// goto loc_1000112C;
    esi = 0x20;
    break;
case 4:
// goto loc_10001133;
    esi = 0x38;
    break;
default:
// goto loc_10001141;
    esi = *(esp+0xC)
    break;
}
```

I have to translate a small assembly code into C, and as a total noob in assembly programming, I need your help.

I already find the solution (which you can see above) because the exercises come from a book, but it does not help me to understand.

So, I had hard work trying to understand the relation between the assembly code and the switch in the solution. I think this is because I cant tell exactly how the code is executed with the assembly code.

(Update: Trying to make a more clear/specific question ^^) : How does the jump table works, and how the code is executed - Assembly code, not the C - ;)

I do not know if I was clear enough, as I said, I'm a newbie here, and English is not my native language! ^^

Comment: Please post the code in your question.

Comment: It could help if you a) posted your code and b) told which platform your using. Don't give links...

Comment: I'm also reasonably sure that the book you linked is not legally available for free (making the link something between illegal and amoral)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code, for start.
Assembly

```
01:   cmp     edi, 5
02:   ja      short loc_10001141    
03:   jmp     ds:off_100011A4[edi*4]
04: loc_10001125:                   
05:   mov     esi, 40h              
06:   jmp     short loc_10001145
07: loc_1000112C:                   
08:   mov     esi, 20h              
09:   jmp     short loc_10001145
10: loc_10001133:                   
11:   mov     esi, 38h              
12:   jmp     short loc_10001145
13: loc_1000113A:                   
14:   mov     esi, 30h              
15:   jmp     short loc_10001145
16: loc_10001141:                   
17:   mov     esi, [esp+0Ch]    
18: ...
19: off_100011A4 dd offset loc_10001125
20:   dd offset loc_10001125           
21:   dd offset loc_1000113A
22:   dd offset loc_1000112C
23:   dd offset loc_10001133
24:   dd offset loc_1000113A
```

Pseudo C

```
switch(edi) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
    // goto loc_10001125;
    esi = 0x40;
    break;
  case 2:
  case 5:
    // goto loc_1000113A;
    esi = 0x30;
    break;
  case 3:
    // goto loc_1000112C;
    esi = 0x20;
    break;
  case 4:
    // goto loc_10001133;
    esi = 0x38;
    break;
  default:
    // goto loc_10001141;
    esi = *(esp+0xC)
    break;
}
...
```

By analysing assembly code, you can see that for edi == 1 and for edi == 0, you jump to the same instruction. Same applies for edi == 2 and edi ==5. In the Pseudo C, you do have strange order of case statements, but notice that some of them are mising break at the end.

Imagine edi == 2, you go to case 2 in Pseudo C, and then go to case 5 in Pseudo C and assign 0x30 to esi. Imagine edi == 5, you go to case 5 in Pseudo C and assign 0x30 to esi. Pseudo C is made like this in order to have less instructions, and smaller executable at the end.